# Latex algorithmic package error "a missings \item"

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I'm trying to compile my text and getting an error from the following oart

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{$Point2PointCollision()$}
\label{P2P}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State {\textbf{Input:} $bla bla$}
\State {\textbf{Output:} $bla bla$}
\State {calculate $blabla$}
    \If {$bla bla$} 
    \State {$bla bla$}
    \Else 
    \State {$bla bla$}
    \EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

error is

> LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.383 \end{algorithmic}
> ```

Here is themain tex file:

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt]{Latex/Classes/PhDthesisPSnPDF}

% put the packages you want to use here
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for pdf, bitmapped graphics files
\usepackage{epsfig} % for postscript graphics files
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{epstopdf} % for postscript graphics files
\usepackage{times} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{amsmath} % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amssymb}  % assumes amsmath package installed
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{algorithm}  %for algorithm environment
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Definition}
\usepackage{bm,upgreek}
\usepackage{bmpsize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\include{3_chapter/chapter}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I try to compile your code, it works fine. The error must be somewhere else, in something you didn't put in the question

Comment: It worked before and I didn't change any part of it. The error addresses the following line : "\end{algorithmic} "

Comment: Well there's nothing wrong with that snippet, and it's not sufficient to reproduce your problem. You'll have to add all the code necessary to reproduce the issue, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: Yes, @user70299 please provide a minimal working example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). Also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I updated the question. The annoying thing is I saved its previous version which was working in mid April. and now it also gives the same error.